# Rounder corners with CSS3 or with images?

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

What is the difference and the best way to create them right now ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS3, definitely. It's faster and cleaner and is supported on all major browsers. IE needs (suprise, suprise) a [workaround though](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius.htc):

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
```

Answer (score 2):

In simple words:

The rounded corners created with images should and work across all browsers.

And those created with CSS3 work in modern browsers but not the IE < 9.

> What is the difference and the best
>   way to create them right now ?

You should use CSS3's `borer-radius` propery along with vendor-specific prefixes for the modern browsers. To get rounded corners working in IE as well, you can use:

- [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/)

> PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-8
>   capable of rendering several of the
>   most useful CSS3 decoration features.

Here is an example of cross-browser rounded corners:

```
#myAwesomeElement {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(path/to/PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: IIRC IE8 doesn't support them as well.

Comment: Almost every post has to end with "except IE".

Comment: A couple of minor typos "borer radius propery" (just after the first quote block).

Comment: I was just about to add CSSPIE. It's awesome and working across all IE versions and it support other CSS3 features too like the gradients and the shadow.

By the way, webkit based browsers doesn't require the -webkit prefix now

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery Plugin [CurvyCorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/)

if you do not want to use css3

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery plugin lc_roundz http://coffeelog.itsatony.com/?p=86 will do the job dynamically - even if you want the corners to be transparent (e.g. for use on complex backgrounds, ...).

```
$("#image").lc_roundz({  
radius: 20,  // corner-radius  
newDadSelector: "", // jQuery style selector string to allow attachment anywhere in the DOM. empty string will inject the canvas next to the original  
newid: "%oid_after_lc_roundz",      // the new ID for the canvas object. %oid will be replaced with the id of the original object  
width: -1,                                                           // -1 uses the original image's width  
height: -1,                    // -1 uses the original image's width  
replace: false,                                          // boolean to decide whether the original should be removed from the DOM  
corner_color: [0,0,0,0]                     // this means TRANSPARENT ... R,G,B,alpha [0-255] each  
});
```